# superagent global .end function handler

Tags: javascript, ajax, superagent

how to add superagent global end handler?

I am using superagent to do ajax data fetching job.

```
request.get('/some/end/point/').end(function(err, res) {

   if (res.status === 401) {
       // redirect to login
   }

   else {
      //do something with the data
   }
});
```

I want to add `if (res.status === 401)` check for every request,

is that possible?

Comment: Did you try it, should work fine ?

Comment: Read the docs...all 4xx status will go to error handler

Comment: @charlietfl I knew it will goes to error handler, but even in this case, I should repeat .on('error', handler) in every request code? my purpose is to do some global config

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-defaults. Quick search in github repo came across this

Comment: I also looked about superagent-defaults before, but seems it can not set an ".end" function